# bash: No such file or directory when file is clearly present

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I have a shell script located at `/home/pi/scripts/take-snapshot.sh` but, whenever I try to execute it, I get a error that the file is not present.

the following commands **do not** work (assuming in script directory):

```bash
/home/pi/scripts/take-snapshot.sh
./take-snapshot.sh
take-snapshot.sh
bash /home/pi/scripts/take-snapshot.sh
```

the following **do** work and will bring up the shell file (not a new file):

```bash
vi take-snapshot.sh
nano take-snapshot.sh
```

Comment: What's the first line of `take-snapshot.sh` ?

Comment: The third one probably won't work even if the file is executable. The current working directory is typically not added to the search path for security reasons.

Comment: It should just be your permissions. Try `chmod 755 /home/pi/scripts/take-snapshot.sh && /home/pi/scripts/take-snapshot.sh`.   
The optional first line ("shebang") in your script can specify the shell interpreter - it isn't strictly needed in your case assuming you are already using /bin/bash as your login shell. Nor will it cause the error you see unless the shebang path is bad. (A bad shebang path will show: `bad interpreter: No such file or directory`)

Comment: That error does not match what bash would output if it did not find the file.  Please copy and paste the actual complete error.

Answer (score 5):

The most likely cause is that your file is not executable. Bash is a bit confusing in that it reports the file as "not found", even though you only don't have permissions to execute it. Run `ls -l` and check the permissions. The leftmost column should show an "x" at least for the current user. It will usually look something like `-rwxr-xr-x` for a file you have created yourself.

Run `chmod +x take-snapshot.sh` to fix the permissions if they don't match.

Comment: note: `bash script.sh` will execute `script.sh` regarless if it's executale or not

Comment: @hek2mgl Oh, didn't know about that, but apparently you are right. Then there's maybe something else wrong as well.

Comment: The OP may simply have the wrong absolute path as well; I wonder what `vi /home/pi/scripts/take-snapshot.sh` does.

Comment: Correct. (`bash` or `/bin/bash` prepended to script call can execute script without execute permissions)..... Unless of course the login shell also can't find `bash`. In this case maybe his env/$PATH is bad.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this error when the line endings are windows EOL characters.  It doesn't give any other error, just the above "No file or directory".

Check the EOL character and convert it to linux EOL, if it is windows and try to run the script again.

Comment: `dos2unix` is the command you need for that.

Comment: Not all systems have that installed, so I didn't mention it.  In fact, our systems do not have that installed.   And That would be how to fix it.  I was just identifying the cause for the error.  People can fix it using vim or sed or other utilities

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this error because my binary was built dynamically on a very different system than I was trying to run it on (ubuntu vs nixos). I now know that this error can be triggered when an executable needs an "interpreter" (or, as in my case, a linker) to be in a specific location, different than its location on the running system. Building the binary on a system matching the target fixed the problem.